# Flutter can't recognize android sdk

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-2.3

I'm running Ubuntu 20 and trying to setup flutter enironment without android studio. Installed android sdk manually && it's path is `$HOME/android`.

here's a log of the directory

```sh
$ ls
# cmdline-tools  licenses
$ ls cmdline-tools/
# latest  tools
ls cmdline-tools/latest
bin  lib  NOTICE.txt  package.xml  source.properties
```

And here's sys vars which are in `~/.bashrc`

```sh
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/android"
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools"
```

And here's `flutter doctor - v` log

```sh
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    • Android SDK at /home/aybak3k/android/
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/aybak3k/android/
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/aybak3k/android
    ✗ Android SDK file not found: adb.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Comment: `~/.bashrc~` perhaps `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter can't recognize the sdk unless you install the rest of the components

the following worked

```sh
# 30 is my physical device compatible version
sdkmanager --install "build-tools;30.0.2"
sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because is missing `/sdk`

Try to change `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/android"`

to `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/android/sdk"`

if not work, try to check the full path to `platform-tools`

### run `which adb`

$HOME/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: first appraoch didn't work
and for `which adb` it's not installed
but aren't the platform tools installed when the flutter app is ran for the first time?

Comment: no, you must to install it.

Can you try that?
flutter config --android-sdk "<android-folder>\cmdline-tools\latest\bin"

or can you install Android Studio? it make this simpler

Comment: thank you I already figured out and came back after testing it on another pc